# JComboBox on Java 11 does not show popup menu on the first mouse click if the parent window is not in the focus

Tags: java, swing, java-11

After a switch of JRE from J8 to J11 JComboBox instances in two different JPanels respectively (both in a JDesktopPane) don't display the popup menu when a respective containing JPanel is not in the focus when a click is happening.
The first click brings focus into the respective JPanel. After that a single click on JComboBox causes the menu to pop up.

This changed when I switched the JRE from 8 to 11.

From the end user perspective it looks like a mess, because most components on the panel don't act like this and correctly do mouse click stuff regardless of the parent panel focus status.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. I use JDK11 on Windows 10 and don't notice the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [this commit](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/4b8cfe5a6058cdada1ad6efbb8f81e2f8f53a177) for [this ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173739): `JInternalFrame` generates `UngrabEvent` when unselected, which causes `JComboBox` popup to hide.